# How to find hotels filtered by a specific keyword?

Tags: hotels, bookings

I'm planning a winter vacation somewhere in Central Europe and would like to find a hotel with a fireplace somewhere in the mountains. Surprisingly though I haven't been able to find a search engine which lets me filter the search results by a specific keyword ("fireplace" in this example)

Is there a convenient way to find a list of hotels filtered by a custom keyword? Websites like Booking.com only let you choose from a limited set of amenity filters.

Comment: have you tried to use google?

Comment: Maybe if you narrow down the specific location a bit, you could contact a local agency?

Comment: Most of the fireplaces are either not functioning or have been replaced with fake electric "fires".

Comment: try this search:
name_of_the_city fireplace hotel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these in search engine in google:

inurl:tripadvisor.com "fireplace" "central europe" "hotel"
inurl:booking.com "fireplace" "central europe" "hotel"

Add more keywords to place a specific country, etc.

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution, but it seems like there is none. I'll accept this as the answer.